# Header Enrichment not working on HTTPs - nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, http-headers, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have multiple questions regarding Header Enrichment with SSL + nginx

1. Why Header Enrichment dose not work with Https ?
2. One of my project have HE(Header Enrichment) enabled on simple HTTP but when we look for specific headers like msisdn in HTTPs they are missing.
3. I am using nginx hence i tried to add headers and return the request from http to https but no result? How can i achieve this ? Following is the sample of nginx code block.

   ```
   server {
       listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
       listen   [::]:80; ## listen for ipv6

   location / {
           add_header X-my-header my-header-content;
           return 301 https://$host$request_uri?msisdn=$http_MSISDN;
      }


   }
   ```
4. I have tried adding Query parameter and it works fine but i am more concerned about headers way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### (1),(2)

ISPs impalement HE by injecting some headers in the request. This can be done in Http as they can easily inspect the request but this is not possible in case of Https as the request is encrypted.

There are some trials to provide alternative solutions but there is neither solid nor standardized one till now.

See more: https://blog.apnic.net/2016/10/13/challenges-of-https/

#### (3)

I suggest to ask this in separate question. However, I noticed that you didnt configured https endpoint in nginx. Please refer to:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

#### (4)

Query paramters are part of URL which can be HTTP or HTTPs or any other protocol. These differ from headers which are part of message itself.